# How can I refer to the value set by useState immediately afterwards?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Continuous React.useState() setter does not work.

```
const [balance, setBalance] = React.useState(0);
const [campaigns, setCampaigns] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log('first use Effect');
  getRequest(`/api/v1/tablet/campaigns/) // getRequest return Promise Obj
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result); // [{...},{...},・・・,{...}]

    setCampaigns(result);

    console.log(campaigns); // [] this is problem part
  });
}, []);
```

How can I refer to the value set by useState immediately afterwards?

Comment: Is it not safe to just use the same `result` that you pass to `setCampaigns` since calling `setCampaigns` will not modify `result` in any way?

Comment: What is the purpose? why you don't just use the `result` as this is only the first render

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the value you set it with until the next refresh of the component, as state only updates on rerender

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to track it in a separate `useEffect`, where you receive the updated value:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(campaigns);
}, [campaigns])
```

Another option is to use the value that was set on the state instead of the actual state value:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log('first use Effect');
  getRequest(`/api/v1/tablet/campaigns/) // getRequest return Promise Obj
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result); // [{...},{...},・・・,{...}]

    setCampaigns(result);

    console.log(result); // Access the result here, which is the same as campaigns
  });
}, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually it works you cant see campaigns in console because setCampaigns works async.

```
const [balance, setBalance] = React.useState(0);
const [campaigns, setCampaigns] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log('first use Effect');
  getRequest(`/api/v1/tablet/campaigns/) // getRequest return Promise Obj
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result); // [{...},{...},・・・,{...}]

    setCampaigns(result);//this function works

    console.log(campaigns); // but setCampaigns function works async
  });
}, []);
```

If you want to access it immediately you need to write below code that means when change campaigns object automatically trigger useeffect function

```
   React.useEffect(() => {         
        console.log(campaigns); // you can see your state data
      });
    }, [campaigns]);
```